# Universal Link to Perform Background Task?

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to perform a background task when a user taps a universal link in another app? Rather than moving my app into the foreground, I'd like it to perform a task while the user continues on their business in the app they're currently using, assuming my app is installed.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some hacky ways to handle it, but as for official documentation I don't think you can run background task without universal link triggers your app to the foreground.

Universal links are handled on `application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:` instance method.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/handling_universal_links

`application(_:open:options:)` is used for handling URL, such as URL Schemes.

Since both of those methods are invoked after `applicationWillEnterForeground` delegate method, I think the answer of your question is no.